# distanceField in geoNear in Spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring-data-mongodb.

1. can I fire a geoNear query using aggregation.
2. Can I specify distanceField in geoNear query as we do in mongodb.

Below is the sample mongodb query :-

```
([
{
    $geoNear: {
        near: [
            28.45,
            77.34
        ],
        distanceField: "distance",
        maxDistance: 20,
        num: 5,
        query: {
            $or: [
                {
                    cuisines: {
                        '$in': [
                            'Mughlai',
                            'NorthIndian'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
$unwind: '$ProducerTimeSlots'
}
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend Aggregation Operation capabilities, GeoNearOperations class doesn't have distanceField variable.

```
public class GeoNearOperationExt implements AggregationOperation {

private NearQuery nearQuery;

private String distanceField = "distance";

public GeoNearOperationExt(NearQuery nearQuery) {
    this.nearQuery = nearQuery;
}

/**
 * Default is distance
 * @return
 */
public String getDistanceField() {
    return distanceField;
}

/**
 * Set distanceField value Default is distance
 * @param distanceField
 */
public void setDistanceField(String distanceField) {
    this.distanceField = distanceField;
}



@Override
public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
    DBObject dbObject = context.getMappedObject(nearQuery.toDBObject());
    dbObject.put("distanceField", distanceField);
    return new BasicDBObject("$geoNear", dbObject);
}
}
```

To use it in aggregation simply include it in array of aggregate operations i.e. parameters passed to aggregate function.